# Border radius in IE7+

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

I want rounded corner support in IE7 & IE8. I am using border-radius.htc file for that. It works perfectly with all corners having same border radius, but it does not work if I change the border radius of any of the corners. My code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Border Radius for IE7+</title>
<style>
.borderRadius{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="borderRadius">
        Content in Div.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine. But it doesn't work if i change the style to

```
<style>
.borderRadius{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
</style>
```

It keeps all the rounded corners with same radius. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: try not using the shorthand for border radius http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the border-radius.htc script has bugs or isn't capable of having different radii for each corner.

I would suggest trying an alternative script; there are several out there, but the best one (by a long way) is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) -- it's got a *lot* more features than any of the other similar scripts, it performs better, and is well tested so probably has fewer bugs and quirks. It's also the only one that I know of that is still under active development. I strongly recommend it.

In theory, it should be a simple case of swapping your existing `behavior()` to reference the PIE.htc file instead, and then working from there.

It should definitely work with your code for varied border radii:

```
border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/62ESq/

I greatly exaggerated the radii so that you could see it was working, but give that a shot.

CSS:

```
.borderRadius{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
     behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```